# How to reverse a string in java programming language without any build in function?

Tags: java, string

How to reverse a string in java programming language?
without use of any built in function.

Comment: Copy the string into a character array, reverse that, make a new String out of it.

Comment: Iterate over the string in the reverse order, read the characters and append them to a new, initially empty string.

Comment: The problem is ill-defined. You **have** to call some built-in functions (methods, actually) to even get to the content of a `String` (for example `toCharArray`).

Comment: This question is meaningful and may be resolved _without_ built-in functions only in languages like good old `C` where a String is a synonym of char array `char[]` or a sequence of char ending with `\0` (ASCIIZ strings) referred by `char*` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can do it by converting it into a `char` array and prepending each element of the array onto an empty string:

```
public class ReverseString{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String str = "abcde";
        //make char array
        char[] array = new char[str.length()]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) { 
            array[i] = str.charAt(i); 
        } 

        //reverse by prepending to a string
        String newString = "";
        for (char character : array){
            newString = character + newString;
        }
        
        System.out.println(newString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Two _built-in functions_ `length()` and `charAt()` are used here :)  And use of intermediate `array` along with the additional loop seems to be redundant.

Comment: Could be wrong, but I think the OP may have meant to say only using built in functions.  The code is redundant, but I wanted to go with what some other comments were saying about iterating to explain the idea.